# How to create pivot screens in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, pivot, three.js

How can I create such an effect in Javascript (Three.js usind canvas elements?) like there described?

Pivot Screen:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/27/what-web-designers-can-learn-from-video-games/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to search for people who have done projective/perspective transforms in Canvas.

ie, http://acko.net/files/projective/index.html

Skewing alone is not particularly hard, all you need really is:

`ctx.setTransform (1, .3, 0, 1, 0, 0);`

But getting true perspective is non-trivial math

Comment: well so i have to do it manually and there are no final scripts for this which i could use directly for this effect?

Comment: There's nothing built in sadly. You'll have to find a script or a tutorial. I don't know of any particularly good libraries for doing it with Canvas yet.

Comment: but i can animate settransform (... skewX and skewY) parameters, right? Like css transitions / animations in jquery?